# filtering nearly duplicate data based on a column condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, here is an example:

```
names  subject     date       marks
A        X      15-05-2021     10
A        X      22-05-2021     12
A        X      29-05-2021     11
A        Y      15-05-2021     15
A        Y      22-05-2021     10
B        P      22-05-2021     17
B        P      29-05-2021     16
B        Q      29-05-2021     14
B        R      22-05-2021     16
```

I need to filter out all names, dates and subjects for which data is available for "29-05-2021".

this is what I need:

```
names  subject     date       marks
A        X      15-05-2021     10
A        X      22-05-2021     12
A        X      29-05-2021     11
B        P      22-05-2021     17
B        P      29-05-2021     16
B        Q      29-05-2021     14
```

I have figured out how to do this, but I think it can be improved.

this is what I am doing as of now:

```
df = pd.read_excel("",name="sheet")
end_date = "29-05-2021"
end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date)
mask = df["date"] == end_date
temp_df = df.loc[mask]
temp_df = temp_df[["names","subject"]]
result_df = pd.merge(df,temp_df, on = ["names","subject"],how="right"]
```

is there any scope of improvement?

Answer (score 1):

I think for performance is your solution good, a bit simplified with remove `on` (because joined by intersection of columns names, here `name, subject`) and need inner join, which is default, so also should be omitted:

```
end_date = "29-05-2021"

mask = df["date"] == pd.to_datetime(end_date)
result_df = pd.merge(df,df.loc[mask, ["names","subject"]])
print (result_df)
  names subject       date  marks
0     A       X 2021-05-15     10
1     A       X 2021-05-22     12
2     A       X 2021-05-29     11
3     B       P 2021-05-22     17
4     B       P 2021-05-29     16
5     B       Q 2021-05-29     14
```

Alternative solution with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) is a bit slowier if large `DataFrame`s:

```
end_date = "29-05-2021"

mask = df["date"] == pd.to_datetime(end_date)
df = df[df.assign(m = mask).groupby(['names','subject'])['m'].transform('any')]
```

Comment: i mean i need to run this code on 1000's of rows of data ,so mine would be better in terms of efficiency right?

Comment: @Tarandeepsingh - My opinion - The best test. I guess yes. I am sure `groupby.filter` is slowiest.

Comment: @Tarandeepsingh - only remove `how="right"`, need inner join (which is default)

Answer (score 1):

Just groupby, and filter any date that has your specs.

```
df.groupby(['names','subject']).filter(lambda x:(x['date']=='29-05-2021').any())
```

Comment: Maybe add to answer solution is good if small DataFrame or performance not important.